# Can't see background image running webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am recently learning React and have problem setting webpack. I wrote a background image in sass file but I can't see this image in browser, I checked the develope tool and saw a strange file name as the attatched picture shows. There's no error when I run webpack. I think I might set the webpack.config.js incorrectly. Can somebody take a look for me? here's the source code:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill',
        './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|gif|png)$/,
                loader: "file"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|gif|png)$/,
                loader: "url"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body',
        })
    ]
};
```

I also put my files on github: https://github.com/john650914/ReactQuestion.git

[image: strange file name]

**Thank you very much~~~~~~~~~**

Answer (score 0):

Webpack will start looking for your url path at `'/'` which was set by your **publicPath** in your `webpack.config.js`

Looking at your repository with your link provided:
https://github.com/john650914/ReactQuestion.git

It seems like your image isn't in your projects root. You should specify the correct publicPath that leads to where you store your assets. So for example if you stored your images in `/src/assets/` then your **publicPath** should be `./src/assets/` like this:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: './src/assets/'
},
```